# Форма в jsp возвращает текст в windows-1252

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, кодировка

Все данные на странице отображаются правильно. Текст, доставаемый из бд, в том числе. Но при отправке формы, в контроллер текст приходит в windows-1252.

В jsp кодировка указана

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
```

Так же указал кодировку для самой формы

```
    <form:form method="POST" action="/event" modelAttribute="message" acceptCharset="UTF-8">
```

В `web.xml` установил фильтр

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>encoding-filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>
        org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter
    </filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>encoding-filter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 1):

Данная проблема возникает, если фильтр-декодер стоит не первым. В моем случае виноват был `spring security`. После того, как перенес всю конфигурацию из `java config` в `xml` и поставил декодер до фильтра `spring security`, данные начали приходить в правильной кодировке.